# How to re-enable Nvidia Driver after Software Update?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have Ubuntu 14.05 installed with an Nvidia Driver.  After recent automatic software updates, the Nvidia driver was disabled and when I rebooted, the standard driver was enabled.  How do I re-enable the Nvidia driver?

NOTE: I tried to re-install the NVIDIA driver, but had problems.  It requires the kernel source code and that now seems to be missing.  I can't install the kernel source now because the machine is now off the internet.

Comment: Re-enable your computer instead IMHO, see previous comment.

Comment: If this is an exact duplicate, please point me to the existing question that was already answered.

Answer (score 0):

Download the binary package from [nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us)

Switch to tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1)

Stop lightdm with `sudo service lightdm stop`

`cd` to the folder where you have the driver binary

run it with `sudo ./nameofthebinary` and follow the steps of the installer

reboot.

Comment: I did exactly that and the install failed.  It complained that it did not have the kernel source code.

Comment: maybe try `apt-get source linux-source` and then repeat the procedure? I'm just guessing now.

Comment: I think you are trying to be helpful, so thank you.  But the machine isn't connected to the internet.

Comment: hmm, ok. I guess there's no much more I can do to help. sorry